# Did NIV overplay the word παρατίθημι in Acts 17:3 "explaining and proving that the Messiah had to suffer and rise from the dead"?

Tags: acts

> New International Version Acts 17:2 As was his custom, Paul went into the synagogue, and on three Sabbath days he **reasoned** with them from the Scriptures, 3 **explaining** and **proving** that the Messiah had to suffer and rise from the dead. "This Jesus I am proclaiming to you is the Messiah," he said.

proving
παρατιθέμενος (paratithemenos)
Verb - Present Participle Middle - Nominative Masculine Singular
Strong's Greek 3908: From para and tithemi; to place alongside, i.e. Present; by implication, to deposit.

> New American Standard Bible
> explaining and **giving evidence** that the Christ had to suffer and rise again from the dead, and saying, "This Jesus whom I am proclaiming to you is the Christ."

In https://biblehub.com/acts/17-3.htm, 6 out of 28 versions use the word to *prove* to translate παρατιθέμενος. Are they overstating παρατίθημι?

Comment: KJV and YLT agree _opening and alleging_. Interesting : 'alleging' not 'proving'. Evidencing ? (+1)

Comment: Present participle is used as continuous in many versions- "everyone believing will not die but have eternal life". See the literal versions like YLT, SLT, Godbey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of quintessential Hebrew thinking in contradistinction to Greek thinking.

First, the meaning of the word:  BDAG suggests that παρατίθημι in Acts 17:3 is παρατιθέμενος which is Verb - Present Participle **Middle** - Nominative Masculine Singular.  Note the **middle** voice.  BDAG gives this meaning here:

> #2 **to set forth in teaching** - ... (b) (middle voice) ***demonstrate, point out***, διανοίγων καὶ παρατιθέμενος, Acts 17:3.  See also Acts 28:23.

Thus, to demonstrate or "prove" is a valid meaning.  However, this is not "proof" in the Euclidean sense of mathematical/geometrical rigor.  The meaning here is a quintessential Hebrew sense, the way much of the OT is presented in Hebrew parallelism - a *placing data beside other data* to show beyond doubt that Jesus is the Messiah.  Hence, Luke's choice of words, διανοίγων καὶ παρατιθέμενος.

The modern English use of "proof"/"prove" is more in the ancient Greek Euclidean sense of mathematical/geometrical proof, but Paul uses Hebrew reasoning.

Versions other than NIV also have "proving" or "demonstrating" such as: NLT, ESV, BSB, NKJV, CSB, NET, NHEB, WEB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a Jewish synagogue, the Law and Prophets would be accepted as hard fact. Also in the the minds of the New Testament writers, the Law and Prophets would be accepted as hard fact. So "demonstrate" or "prove" would be valid. For someone who doesn't accept Luke's worldview that scripture is as good as proven fact, that person would not perceive that "prove" were an accurate description of what happened.